# Simple use of b2ContactListener in box2d based game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am using box2d based game and i want to detect collision between my sprite body and edge body. I know use of b2Contactlistener in [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2010/03/04/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone/) but i want to use contactlistener in simplest form.
Is any one know than help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has a simple example (same site): http://www.raywenderlich.com/28606/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-part-2